# Does Cisco anyconnect replace original network connection session?

Tags: networking, vpn

When using Cisco anyconnect VPN, it seems the existing network connection is still going through old connection session (Is there any way to find out)?

The reason is because when using Cisco VPN client connect to gateway, usually the Messenger Live, Skype will be disconnected and requires to reconnect. But using anyconnect doesn't need to reconnect.

So I am guessing if those old sessions still go through original network connection. Which means, both connection is existing at the same time.

Take my case for example:
connection 1: wireless NIC -> cable modem -> my cable ISP -> internet
connection 2: anyconnect -> wireless NIC -> cable modem -> my cable ISP -> VPN gateway -> internet

Am I correct? Is there any way to check this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Run a traceroute for an IP on the internal network (vpn network), and a traceroute for an external IP while connected to the vpn.  That should tell you where your traffic is going, whether it's tunneling through the vpn or exiting your local gateway to the internet through your ISP.  Normally if the VPN is configured properly, only LAN traffic bound for the VPN will route through the VPN tunnel and all else will route out your local internet gateway (why your stuff is staying up after connecting with Anyconnect).   The older VPN Client might have blocked local internet access and forced routing through the VPN connection for all traffic, dropping your messenger, skype, etc.  It depends on how the client routing is configured in the ASA or PIX and whether you have local lan access enabled.